# Django - Extend User Twice Using AbstractUser

Tags: django, authentication, model

I'd like to have both Teacher and Student Accounts in my Django WebApp. Now I have extended the base user using Student(AbstractUser) and AUTH_USER_MODEL='mainApp.Student'.

Now I'd like to implement a Teacher Account, using the same approach. But before I wreck my project I wanted to ask for input. Do you think this can work or should I use a OneToOneField or maybe just a is_teacher / is_student boolean?

I'd like to avoid using a OneToOneField, as that creates the need to first create a User and then also create a Student / Teacher.

Comment: What would be the difference between a `Student` and `Teacher`? Can't a user be both a user and student?

Comment: You can create single model and add field say role which can distinguish whether the user is student or teacher.